# PHP object (not class) is not available in another class

Tags: php, object, scope

I read that objects (instantiations of classes) are of global scope. This makes sense because objects (again, I am not talking about classes) should be easy to be reused in other parts of the code. But it seems that this information is wrong. Look at this example:

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

$testobject = new test();


class getvalue {

    private $var;

    function printvalue() {
            $var = $testobject->returnvalue;
            print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue();
$getvalueobject->printvalue();

?>
```

This code returns the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in ...

So, what would I have to do to make the $testobject (instantiation of class "test") available in class getvalue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pass it to the method. They are not in the same scope as like superglobals

Comment: Where did you get the idea that objects are always global from?

Comment: I guess I understood something wrong, but for me this is all what are objects about: Having them available freely in your code to use their properties and methods, where I need them. If I have to pass the objects through to the several classes and functions to have it finally available where I need it, I have very strong coupling and this is bad in OOP, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. Objects do not have global scope.

So if you need to use an object in another class then you have to pass it either to the __construct function and store the object in the class properties or you have to pass it to the function where it is used:

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

$testobject = new test();


class getvalue {

    private $var;
    private $testobject;

    function __construct($testobject) {
        $this->testobject = $testobject;
    }

    function printvalue() {
        $var = $this->testobject->returnvalue;
        print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue($testobject);
$getvalueobject->printvalue();

?>
```

or

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

$testobject = new test();


class getvalue {

    private $var;

    function printvalue($testobject) {
        $var = $testobject->returnvalue;
        print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue();
$getvalueobject->printvalue($testobject);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

//$testobject = new test(); MOVE INTO METHOD


class getvalue {

    private $var;

    function printvalue() {
            $testobject = new test(); //For instance here
            $var = $testobject->returnvalue;
            print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue();
$getvalueobject->printvalue();

?>
```

Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks Nytrix, but it makes no sense to instance a new object in getvalue. I need the already existing object that was defined outside of class getvalue. The example is simplified, of course the object has not just a static value defined.

Comment: You could do it as a parameter, or in a constructor of you're getValue class. The `variable` you assign the object too needs to be accesible. So not outside of you're class, then you need to acces it gloably

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

$testobject = new test();


class getvalue {

    public $classObject;

    function printvalue() {
        $var = $this->classObject->returnvalue;
        print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue();
$getvalueobject->classObject = $testobject;
$getvalueobject->printvalue();

?>
```

Example with class extend

```
<?php

class test {
    public $returnvalue = "foobar";
}

// If you use extends in PHP classes you can access all variables and methods from the base class (In this example the base class would be Test)
class getvalue extends test {
    function printvalue() {
        // Because we extended the base class Test, we can access it's public variable returnvalue
        $var = $this->returnvalue;
        print "$var";
    }

}

$getvalueobject = new getvalue();
$getvalueobject->printvalue();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks WannaKnow, but what if there would be several other classes and functions wrapped around class getvalue? Would I have to pass it through all the way from top to the bottom? This is much against what OOP is all about, isn't it?

Comment: No, That isn't the correct way to do it. I changed my orignal post.

Comment: If you do it this why you can call $this->classObject in the entire getvalue class. With $this->classObject you can access the entire 'test' class. If you don't need the $testobject, you can also extend the test class. I will make a example of that also.